# How to check fetched result set is empty or not?

Tags: php, pdo

For example:

```
$sql = 'select a, b, c from table where condition';
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetch();
```

AND

```
 $sql = 'select a, b, c from table where condition';
 $stmt->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute();
 $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

How to check if result set is empty or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `$data` variable like:

```
if ($data) {
  //not empty
} else {
  // empty
}
```

If the result of `SELECT` query did return any data, variable `$data` will contain a non-empty array/object which evaluates to `true`, and a false-like value otherwise.

Comment: Yes, a straight forward solution; though you should perhaps explain *why* that works exactly.

Comment: ok, if i write **$data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);**, then it will be same ?

Comment: thanks, and how to check for insert, update and delete

Comment: @Vladimir delete/update queries may not have a match due to the WHERE clause, but this won't result in an error.